# Unable to start debug from visual studio 2008; unrecognized or unsupported binary format

Tags: visual-studio-2008, debugging, windows-7, 64-bit

I am currently trying to set up my new Laptop for development.
But i encounter the following behaviour:

When i try to build the solution for the first time (or after clean-up) i get the following error:
general error c1010070: Failed to load and parse the manifest
However, this error disappears if i build again. So maybe it doesn't matter, but i mention i if it somehow matters. :-)

After a second build run, i am able to create an executable, but i cannot start i with the "start debugging" command in visual studio.
If i start the application outside vs everything is fine, but as i am developing this thing, i also need to debug. And if possible i want to use the vs debugger.

My system:
Lenovo x220 with Intel core i3 sandybridge
windows 7 32bit installed (i also tried previously with 64bit)
(do you need further infos?)

The vs project:
It is a solution containing one static library project, two dynamic library project, and one that crates the executable
Everything was deigned for 32bit, and the target machine was set to x86.

I had no problems building and running everything on my pc at work, which runs windows 7 64bit, and in a virtual machine running windows 7 32bit on my laptop.

I also searched by maybe i missed some relevant articles.
If so, please point me to that article and take my appologies for asking again.

Thanks for answers in adavance

Comment: Perhaps you are not running Visual Studio with the Run As Administrator option?

Comment: I tried running vs as administrator, but it didn't change anything, both errors (manifest, and unsupported binary format) still happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem was, that my solution was on an ext3 formatted disc. I mounted that disc in Windows 7 with ext2ifs http://www.fs-driver.org/ and enabled write support. Afterwards i tried if i really have write support and everything was fine. But somehow the driver wasn't able to enable this write support always. Thats why VS complained only sometimes that it wasnt able to write the manifest. I copied my solution to an ntfs disc and everthing worked fine. The strange thing is, that i had already tried this before, but then it wouldnt work either. So I am not 100% sure that my solution is indeed the solution. For me it works now. :-)